# Jquery Resizable: Stop Resizable Event Explicitly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, resizable, jquery-ui-resizable, jquery-resizable

I want to stop a resizable event on an element explicitly, which normally ends on  mouseup.
How can do it? What event is called to end the resizable event and how can I call it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are after exactly but I presume you are wanting to stop the ability to resize beyond a certain point.  If so, look at adding a containment area for your resizable element instead.  [Like this from the jQuery UI Resizable documentation](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/#constrain-area).